How to change lowercase to uppercase in multiple choices in regex mode
I have multiple choices
a.  firms and government.
b.  households and firms.
c.  analyzing available data.
d.  being objective.

I want to replace  the them in the following form
A. Firms and government.
B. Households and firms.
C. Analyzing available data.
D. Being objective.


Here is my regex attempt at regex101
Search for  \t[a-z]. \t and replace with [\U\1]
Though I can use a simple replacement in NPP, a.     to A.  to d.       to D.  but regx mode should be more efficient.

Search for ^\h*[a-z]\.\h*[A-Za-z] and replace with \U$0, see the regex demo.

You are using group 1 in your replacement, but your regex does not have a group 1. You can just use the full match \U$0 instead.

thx. if there is further way to slim the wide space "A.    Frim" to  "A. Firm" with single space only.

Like this? \h*\t([a-z]\.)\h+([a-zA-Z]) https://regex101.com/r/F9ANJy/1 and replace with \U$1 \U$2

You can use
Find What: ^\h*([a-z]\.)\h*([a-zA-Z])
Replace With: \U$1 $2
See the regex demo.
Details

^ - start of a line (in NPP)
\h* - any zero or more horizontal whitespaces
([a-z]\.)  - Group 1: an ASCII letter (lowercase, but it can match uppercase, too if you select a Match case option)
\h* - any zero or more horizontal whitespaces
([a-zA-Z]) - Group 2: any ASCII letter
\U$1 $2 - \U turns the next characters to uppercase, and $1 / $2 stand for the text captured into respective groups.

